# C# BotFramework PromptDialog.Choice() Too Many Attempts Handler

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm currently working on a ChatBot, so basically I want a way to handle the "Too Many Attempts" message when the user hit the maximum attempts. Base on this documentation of the  `PromptDialog.Choice()` [link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.promptdialog.choice?view=botbuilder-dotnet-3.0#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_PromptDialog_Choice__1_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_IDialogContext_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_ResumeAfter___0__System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0___System_String_System_String_System_Int32_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_PromptStyle_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_String__System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_System_Double_). The message can be change but there is no parameter or whatsoever to handle the next occurrence of the method.

I have tried to research about scorable-bot that I have researched but in my scope I cannot change the flow of the ChatBot, so I'm stuck at waterfall method in developing the ChatBot.

Any piece of advice will be nice. Thanks.

Also this is the piece of code I've working on:

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomPromptDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        List<string> choices = new List<string>();
        choices.Add("Choice 1");
        choices.Add("Choice 2");
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, ResumeAfter, choices, "Title", "Wrong!", 5);

    }
    public async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
            var choice = await result;
            //A Too Many Attempts handler here

            //Returns the choice to the caller
            context.Done(choice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but I don't know if this a ethical solution.
So when the "Too Many Attempts" message occur, it throws an exception to the `ResumtAfter`. So I just need to take handle the exception. That's it, but for those who have a more good solution to my problem please share it.

```
[Serializable]
public class CustomPromptDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        List<string> choices = new List<string>();
        choices.Add("Choice 1");
        choices.Add("Choice 2");
        PromptDialog.Choice(context, ResumeAfter, choices, "Title", "Wrong!", 5);

    }
    public async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
            try{ 
                 var choice = await result;
                context.Done(choice);
            }catch(Exception e){
                // Code here after "Too Many Attempts" message
            }

    }
}
```